# Popular Chinese language science / engineering video content for children

Tags: resources, culture, technology

What are the most popular Chinese language video programs / online video channels that pertain to science, chemistry, math, robotics, etc. with a focus on kids as the audience?

Equivalent to English-language channels Mark Rober, Steve Mould, Numberphile, Periodic Videos, NileRed, etc.

Comment: 李永樂老師： https://www.youtube.com/c/%E6%9D%8E%E6%B0%B8%E4%B9%90%E8%80%81%E5%B8%88

Comment: 又來了:　https://www.youtube.com/c/%E4%BD%91%E4%BE%86%E4%BA%86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer includes some already mentioned in the comments to OP's question.

1. 李永乐老师 - https://www.youtube.com/@TchLiyongle -
   He covers a lot of topics incl. stats, physics, economy.
2. 佑來了 - https://www.youtube.com/@yoyophysics -
   Mainly deep dives of physics experiments on commonly seen phenomena.
3. 妈咪说 MommyTalk - https://www.youtube.com/@Sci1729 -
   Physics, math, basic science.
4. 柴知道 ChaiKnows - https://www.youtube.com/@chaiknowsofficialchannel982 -
   Knowledge in daily lives, incl. some science.